# Leaflet, can not find marker.onLatlngUpdate() or anything similar to it

Tags: leaflet

I am working on a leaflet markers clustering algorithm, everything is going fine until a `marker` updates its `latlng`, I need to reset the marker position in the cluster tree.

In short words, i need to call a function just everytime the `marker` calls `setLatLng()`

Comment: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/e9bc85952d955347bbfd0a2d7909fdc51f08a48a/src/layer/marker/Marker.js#L144-L153

Answer (score 1):

Thx to [IvanSanchez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4768502/ivansanchez) comment, now I see that `leaflet` already fires `move` event when we use `setLatLng()` on a marker

But in my case I need the event only when the marker uses `setLatLng()` with new coordinates than before, and the solution for that is to just check if the old and new `latlng` are equal or not

```
marker.on('move', event =>{
    if(event .oldLatLng.equals(event .latlng))
    console.log("hello I've just moved")
})
```